# How to display an image using img tag if located in downloads folder of C drive?

Tags: html, xampp, wampserver

I'm using WampServer. Now I want to display and image that is not in **www** folder. It is located in **C** drive's **Downloads** folder. I want the users to select image from this folder and it should display it.

When I tried, it showed:

```
<img id="signphoto" src="../../../Users/Vikas/Downloads/dsds.png" />
```

this address and it's not working. **The error was:** GET http://localhost/Users/Vikas/Downloads/dsds.png 404 (Not Found)

How can I change it to work? Is there any way?

Actual source of image is: C:\Users\Vikas\Downloads\dsds.png

Comment: Have you tried: `file:///H:\Images and Wallpapers\ANOKONDA.JPG`?

Comment: No. It's not working. Ok what if the image is in C drive's downloads folder? I tried and it shows this error now: GET http://localhost/Users/Vikas/Downloads/dsds.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do I need to modify this address?

Comment: @user3284463 I've edited my question and details. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a security vulnerability if the client could request local file system files and then use JavaScript to figure out what's in them.

The only way around this is to build an extension in a browser. Firefox extensions and IE extensions can access local resources. Chrome is much more restrictive.

If you use Google chrome browser you can use like this

```
<img src="E://bulbpro/pic_bulboff.gif"   width="150px" height="200px">
```

But if you use Mozila Firefox the you need to add "file " ex.

```
<img src="file:E://bulbpro/pic_bulboff.gif"   width="150px" height="200px">
```

IE 9 : If you want that the user takes a look at image before he posts it to the server : The user should ADD the website to "trusted Website list".

Comment: Ok. I won't use it since you've told about security vulnerability. But what if the image is present in C drive's downloads folder (not inside www folder)? Can I display it without using extensions?

Comment: You are using PHP? You can try above code that was not security issue. @VikasKumar

Comment: I'm using PHP. Now I want to use an image that is in downloads folder. But when I tried just now, it displays error: GET http://localhost/Users/Vikas/Downloads/dsds.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please reply Masud Sarker

Comment: Do you using any PHP Framework Like codeigniter or raw PHP? @VikasKumar

Comment: I'm writing all code by myself. No other tools. I've edited my question.

Comment: If your code www folder and images is in User folder you can try it. src="../../Users/downlods/dsds.png"

Comment: Did you try this line <img src="file:E://bulbpro/pic_bulboff.gif"   width="150px" height="200px">

Comment: Should I replace E by C?

Comment: It works or not? If work you can rate by increasing 1 in comment.

Comment: I didn't try. I don't know how to edit that tag, what to change accordingly.

Comment: It actually doesn't work. When I inspect the element, it says: `Not allowed to load local resource`.